# How to use Firebug Lite API?

Tags: firebug

I want to have a functionality to highlight webpage elements on mouse hover and select them, so that I could get their XPaths etc.

I want to have only this much of functionality for my own use, also which can be run on all browsers if possible.

Can I use firebug lite api or sort of same thing for my needs?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use firebug lite.
You can use firebug standard for this.

Just click in element (in screen).
After, in HTML tab of firebug right-click and choose `Copy XPath`

Answer (score 0):

[Firebug lite](http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite) is nothing more than a javascript file that you inject in your page. You can do so conditionally when you're using a technology like PHP or ASP.NET (or alternatives).

It doesn't however give you the raw/full power you're used to of using firebug itself. Besides if it's only for you, I suggest you simply install firefox in combination with firebug instead.